# Get values of multiple select boxes in PHP and add them to an array

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a button which allows an ingredient to be added to a database. When the button is clicked, the user can add the name, measurement and unit for the ingredient which is done using Javascript:

```
function addIngredient() {
  var area = document.getElementById("addedIngredient");
  var num = document.createElement("p");
  numText = document.createTextNode(countIngredient + ". ");
  num.appendChild(numText);
  area.appendChild(num);

  //Ingredient Name
  var ingredientNameLabel = document.createElement("p");
  ingredientNameLabelText = document.createTextNode("Name");
  ingredientNameLabel.appendChild(ingredientNameLabelText);
  area.appendChild(ingredientNameLabel);
  countIngredient++;

  var ingredientNameInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  ingredientNameInput.setAttribute("name", "ingredient_name[]");
  ingredientNameInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  ingredientNameInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  ingredientNameInput.setAttribute("class", "ingName");
  area.appendChild(ingredientNameInput);

  //Ingredient Measure
  var ingredientMeasureLabel = document.createElement("p");
  ingredientMeasureLabelText = document.createTextNode("Measure");
  ingredientMeasureLabel.appendChild(ingredientMeasureLabelText);
  area.appendChild(ingredientMeasureLabel);

  var ingredientMeasureInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  ingredientMeasureInput.setAttribute("name", "ingredient_measure[]");
  ingredientMeasureInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  ingredientMeasureInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  ingredientMeasureInput.setAttribute("class", "ingMeasure");
  area.appendChild(ingredientMeasureInput);

   //Ingredient Unit
   var ingredientUnitLabel = document.createElement("p");
   ingredientUnitLabelText = document.createTextNode("Unit");
   ingredientUnitLabel.appendChild(ingredientUnitLabelText);
   area.appendChild(ingredientUnitLabel);

   var select = document.createElement("SELECT");
  select.setAttribute("name", "ingredient_unit[]");
  area.appendChild(select);

  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", "grams");
  var value = document.createTextNode("g");
  option.appendChild(value);
  select.appendChild(option);

  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", "milimeters");
  var value = document.createTextNode("ml");
  option.appendChild(value);
  select.appendChild(option);

  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", "kilograms");
  var value = document.createTextNode("kg");
  option.appendChild(value);
  select.appendChild(option);
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", "litres");
  var value = document.createTextNode("litre(s)");
  option.appendChild(value);
  select.appendChild(option);

  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", "slice");
  var value = document.createTextNode("slice");
  option.appendChild(value);
  select.appendChild(option);

  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", "whole");
  var value = document.createTextNode("whole");
  option.appendChild(value);
  select.appendChild(option);

  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("value", "pinch");
  var value = document.createTextNode("pinch");
  option.appendChild(value);
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

I am looking to get the unit selected for every ingredient added.

Can anyone tell me how I could do this using PHP?

I am trying the following way:

```
$units = [];
foreach ($_POST["ingredient_unit[]"] as $key => $unit) {
        array_push($units, $unit);
    }
```

This does not work nor does it give an error.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It's not giving an error. It isn't adding to the array at all.

Comment: `foreach ($_POST["unitList"]` < where is that coming from?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it to what it is. Still no error.

Comment: `foreach ($_POST["ingredient_unit[]"]` < The (inside)`[]` brackets don't belong in there, they belong in the input(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following code:

```
foreach ($_POST["ingredient_unit[]"] as $key => $unit) {
    array_push($units, $unit);
}
```

And use this instead:

```
foreach ($_POST["ingredient_unit"] as $key => $unit) {
    array_push($units, $unit);
}
```

And you should be getting a notice when you try to access `$_POST["ingredient_unit[]"]` since its not defined. If you are not seeing a notice, maybe the error_reporting level is too low. You could use something like the following to active all errors except the **deprecated** ones:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL &~ E_DEPRECATED);
```